# How many tendencies are affected by Gyroscopic precession for single propeller airplane?

Tags: aircraft-performance

[image]

I have heard about LEFT turning tendency affected by gyroscopic precession of propeller (which is turning clockwise or counter clockwise if seen from front side). But I just watched a video on Youtube explains the tendencies affected by the gyroscopic precession, that the airplane is pitch up (nose up or tail down), which means, there are two tendencies.

Then my question is, is that explanation true? Is the second tendency true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both are wrong.** (Or rather, both are partly right, which makes them fundamentally wrong).

Precession happens when there is an 'input' rotation (moment) and not by itself. When you balance the airplane to fly straight <s>and level</s>, there is no gyroscopic moment.

The gyroscopic moment is *perpendicular* to the external rotation, so it can be directed anywhere across the spin axis.

On a typical airplane with the CCW prop (or turbine for that matter), if you yaw (or turn) LEFT, the airplane will want to pitch UP. (See the diagram on your picture). If you pitch UP, the airplane wants to turn RIGHT. If you pitch DOWN, the airplane wants to turn LEFT.<sup>1</sup> And so on. The quicker you maneuver, the stronger the effect is. (And of course, the quicker and heavier the prop is, the stronger the moment, so it's most noticeable at full power).

In normal flying with GA airplanes, the gyroscopic moments are rather minor. The typical 'left turning tendency' is caused by aerodynamics. Gyroscopic moments manifest themselves when rotation is relatively fast, e.g. in aerobatics or spin. But they can be observed with quick impulse inputs on the pedals or yoke, if carefully executed.

---

<sup>1</sup>This latter is particularly noticeable on taildraggers during takeoff when the tail is lifted too quickly: the aerodynamic forces are still weak, and the power is full.

Comment: It's most noticeable on a taildragger if you raise the tail from 3 point to tail high very quickly while taking off.  If it has a large prop at TO power the swing to the left is quite dramatic.

Comment: An excellent demonstration of this principle is to remove the front wheel of a bicycle, hold the axle, and have someone spin it up for you.  Now, try to move the axle one direction or another.  You will see and feel the movement taking affect 90 degrees off from your input.

Comment: Good answer. Would be more precise if you reword the first paragraph to state gyroscopic effect is only present if the aircraft itself is undergoing rotation.

Comment: Doesn't the 2rd paragraph (and all further text) state exactly that?

Comment: @JohnK, thanks, I added this example to the answer.

Comment: @Zeus, to make the same understanding, I assume that we have the same understanding that CCW is seen from front side as in the picture, which actually it is clockwise or CW seen from tail side, which is the correct point of view.

Comment: I have to be very careful to read your explanation. So I will break it to some part to make sure that I understand it correctly.

Comment: (On a typical airplane with the CCW propeller): This one: *If you pitch UP, the airplane wants to turn RIGHT,* and this one: *If you pitch DOWN, the airplane wants to turn LEFT.* -->>I understand. But this one: *If you yaw (or turn) LEFT, the airplane will want to pitch UP.* -->>This is I don't understand. it relevancy probably, *If I yaw (or turn) RIGHT, the airplane will turn pitch down.*

Comment: I tried to search about gyroscopic precession, and I found interesting thing [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPUuF_dECVI), start from 23:00, the turning is proportional to its lean. When he LEAN to RIGHT, it TURN RIGHT. Vice versa, when he LEAN to LEFT, it TURN LEFT. I assuming the bicycle's whee; is the propeller and his left hand is front side of the propeller and his right hand is airplane's body. So, pitch UP is like LEAN to RIGHT which will TURN RIGHT and pitch DOWN is like LEAN to LEFT which will TURN LEFT. Am I right?

Comment: Traditionally, prop direction is defined when viewed from the front: this is how you approach it and how you turn it when starting by hand. Most examples assume (often without stating it) CCW rotation because it's by far the most common on American airplanes. But I agree strictly speaking it needs explicit qualification.

Comment: As for direction, it is always 90° to the applied moment. (Direction of any moment can be defined by the right hand or right screw rule: it goes along the screw when you turn it by the moment in question). Precession is a cross product of the spin and external moments; check the cross product definition to understand its direction. Precession is proportional to the applied moment but not to the angle ('lean'): the stronger your external moment (i.e. the quicker you turn), the stronger the _tendency_ to turn crosswise. ('Turn' here is any rotation across the spin axis, i.e. pitch and yaw).